# Dismiss AlertDialog from within it's button's callback

Tags: android

I want to be able to dynamically dismiss an `AlertDialog` from within it's own button callback:

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setNeutralButton(R.string.enter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            if (/* if some condition is met */) {
                // dismiss the alert
            } else {
                // keep the alert open
            }
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog alert_dialog = alert.create();
    alert_dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST);
    alert_dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    alert_dialog.show();
```

I know that I can call `dismiss()` on `alert_dialog` but I cannot put this call within the very code that creates it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DialogInterface` in the callback is the `Dialog` itself ([`Dialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html) implements `DialogInterface`), so all you have to do is call the [`DialogInterface#dismiss()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html#dismiss()) method:

```
alert.setNeutralButton(R.string.enter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        if (/* if some condition is met */) {
            dialog.dismiss(); // dismiss the alert
        } else {
            // keep the alert open
        }
    }
});
```